# How to get value to Recyclerview-Adapter from another Activity and set value to Recyclerview of particular position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my Application I am opening another `Activity`, lets say `SecondActivity` on item click of `RecyclerView`, `SecondActivity` pass some data to `RecyclerView` adapter on click of submit button (`RecyclerView` adapter holds on `FirstActivity`).

I have to set that data to item click position only, how will I achieve this?

I have tried to get adapter position and used `notifyItemchanged(position)`  in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

Comment: What you have tried. Can you share code?

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ParentViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 holder.tvTotal.setText( Total);
        MovieAdapter.this.notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

Value of Total send by Activity B

Comment: This is wrong way... You have to change data in your string/entity list... and then you have to call `notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition())`

Answer (score 0):

You can set listener either in your ViewHolder class or in onBindViewHolder method.
ViewHolder:

```
public MyViewHolder(View v, final Activity activity) {
            super(v);
            title = v.findViewById(R.id.controller_title);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainPanelActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("controllerName",title.getText().toString());
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
        }
```

onBindViewHold:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Controller controller = controllerList.get(position);
        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CustomControllerInfoDialog dialog = new CustomControllerInfoDialog(activity, holder);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

in ViewHolder you can pass reference of the view and in BindView method you can pass position. so you will be able to add those data where you want